# Compiling tensorflow: undefined reference to `clSetUserEventStatus@OPENCL_1.1'

Tags: tensorflow, clang

*PS: Question is at the end, the following is just background information that might help.*

I'm trying to compile tensorflow, but getting this error:

```
bazel-out/host/bin/_solib_local/_U@local_Uconfig_Usycl_S_Ssycl_Csyclrt___Uexternal_Slocal_Uconfig_Usycl_Ssycl_Slib/libComputeCpp.so:
    undefined reference to `clSetUserEventStatus@OPENCL_1.1'
```

By using "strace" tool, i've isolated the exact statement that's failing to be:

```
(
cd /home/rh/.cache/bazel/_bazel_rh/81919f16ea125cb9f08993f06569f022/execroot/tensorflow && \
exec env - PATH=/home/rh/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.5/bin:/home/rh/perl5/bin:/home/rh/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/rh/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_74/bin:/home/rh/.local/bin:/home/rh/myscripts \
/usr/bin/clang++-3.6 \
-o \
bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/python/gen_functional_ops_py_wrappers_cc \
-Lbazel-out/host/bin/_solib_local/_U@local_Uconfig_Usycl_S_Ssycl_Csyclrt___Uexternal_Slocal_Uconfig_Usycl_Ssycl_Slib \
-Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN/../../_solib_local/_U@local_Uconfig_Usycl_S_Ssycl_Csyclrt___Uexternal_Slocal_Uconfig_Usycl_Ssycl_Slib \
-pthread \
-Wl,-no-as-needed \
-B/usr/bin/ \
-Wl,-no-as-needed \
-Wl,--build-id=md5 \
-Wl,--hash-style=gnu \
-Wl,-S \
-Wl,@bazel-out/host/bin/tensorflow/python/gen_functional_ops_py_wrappers_cc-2.params \
-Wl,--no-undefined
)
```

strace also confirms that this command IS reading `/usr/local/computecpp/lib/libComputeCpp.so`, which contains the aforementioned `clSetUserEventStatus` symbol.

I verified that `libComputeCpp.so` contains `clSetUserEventStatus` by checking the output of the `nm` command:

```
nm /usr/local/computecpp/lib/libComputeCpp.so | grep clSetUserEventStatus
>> U clSetUserEventStatus@@OPENCL_1.1
```

---

**So here is my question**: clang (and/or its linker) is reading the file that contains the symbol that it's complaining about... why is it "missing something" and complaining that it's undefined?

How can I get this compile to work?

Comment: From the output of `nm`, it looks like `clSetUserEventStatus` is *undefined* in `libComputeCpp.so`. I'm not familiar with OpenCL, but I'd guess that it's actually defined in `libOpenCL.so` (or something that it depends on).

Comment: Do you have libOpenCL in your system and it supports OpenCL 1.2 ? you can check with clinfo or computecppinfo...

Comment: @Ruyk: can you tell what is the necessity of OpenCL 1.2 here as the error is pointing towards OpenCL 1.1, facing a similar issue

Comment: ComputeCpp requires at least an OpenCL 1.2 implementation. The symbol was defined on OpenCL 1.1 for the first time, that is what it has the "@@OPENCL_1.1" tag at the end.